# How to organise node positions in D3 Force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a graph that can potentially have 1000's of nodes with a very nested structure, so when I click a node, it will add more children nodes, and so on. Some children can have multiple parents, and some children can have siblings with different parents. I've put a simple [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/t77x8xur/55/) together to demo what I've got so far, with just 2 levels of data for brevity.

This is my simulation setup...

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(mergedData.nodes)
  .velocityDecay(0.55)
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100).distanceMin(10000))
  .force('collide', d3.forceCollide(25))
  .force('link', d3.forceLink(mergedData.links)
     .id((d) => { return d.id; })
     .distance(400)
     .strength(0.1)
  )
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
  .on('tick', ticked);
```

I'm trying to arrange the layout of the nodes so the parent > child relationship is more clear. Ideally I'd like to give the user 2 options, a tree structure, and a radial / grouped structure like so:

[image: illustration to demonstrate node layout]

I'm really struggling to see how I go about doing this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using the v4 API

Answer (score 1):

You can organize the nodes as in the left image using [d3.forceY](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceY), which:

> Creates a new positioning force along the y-axis towards the given position y.

Thus, using your code, you can for instance position the red circles at 100 and the gray circles at 300 in the vertical coordinate with:

```
.force("yPosition", d3.forceY(function(d){
    return d.r === 20 ? 100 : 300
}).strength(2))
```

Im using a `strength` higher than the recommended (between 0 and 1) just for making the circles better aligned in the y position.

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rLf054zy/

PS: I changed your `mergedData` array, which was not properly merging `d1` and `d2`.

Comment: Thanks! The data was merging once you clicked a red circle, but your update makes it a little more obvious. Also thanks for the answer. I've been messing with the node `cx` and `cy` attributes in the tick function with not much luck.

Comment: @DanV Sorry, I missed that event handler. Regarding the `cx` and `cy` attributes, you can combine `d3.forceX/Y` with scales. For instance, this is a force directed chart I made combining them: https://gf.neocities.org/ohp/ohp.html

Comment: Again thanks @Gerardo! That's really helpful. I'd give your answer a green tick, but I'd like to get some more responses first and hopefully get some insight into the other layout.